# Nested boolean queries within $match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've been having trouble finding references to this concept in the documentation so I figured I'd ask here. We're working with some boolean query logic and I've been working on building a `$match` stage with something like the following:

```
{ '$match': 
 { '$or': 
    [ { depth: { '$or': [ { '$gt': 1 }, { '$lte': 36 }, { '$ne': 15 } ] } },
      { height: { '$and': [ { '$gt': 1 }, { '$lte': 36 }, { '$ne': 15 } ] } } ] } },
```

Can anyone confirm if this type of nested boolean logic is supported?

In my testing, it doesn't return any results but it also doesn't raise any exceptions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax should be

```
{$match: {
    $and: [
        {depth: {$gt: 1}},
        {depth: {$lte: 36}},
        {depth: {$ne: 15}},
        {height: {$ne: 15}},
        .... etc ....
    ]
}}
```

Although there's a simpler way for that query..

```
{$match: {
    depth: {$gt: 1, $lte: 36, $ne: 15},
    height: {$gt: 1, $lte: 36, $ne: 15}
}}
```

**UPDATE**

This is your query post-update

```
{$match: {
    $or: [
        {depth: {$gt: 1}},
        {depth: {$lte: 36}},
        {depth: {$ne: 15}},
        {height: {$gt: 1, $lte: 36, $ne: 15}} 
    ]
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think this completely achieves my goal, however, as I'm hoping to be able to combine booleans. I've updated my example to hopefully better illustrate my needs.

Comment: Ahhh that makes perfect sense. Thank you for clarifying! Marking this as the accepted answer.